# Why is cell that contains TRUE not equal to "TRUE"?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Here's my formula: =AND(M2= "FALSE", N2= "TRUE", O2= "A",P2= "No")[image]

And here's the sheet. My value returned false. What do I do?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

The Boolean value `true` is different from the text string `"TRUE"`. Use proper Boolean literals, like this:

```
=and(M2 = false, N2 = true, O2 = "A", P2 = "No")
```

...or, more concisely:

```
=and(not(M2), N2, O2 = "A", P2 = "No")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)